# PNotify on AngularJS: confirm module not working

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, pnotify

I'm working with angularjs, requirejs, bootstrap3 + fontawesome.
PNotify core works great; but everytime I work with buttons and confirm, the buttons wouldn't show up.

I installed PNotify using bower and I included all of modules (pnotify.core.js and all of its js modules) on my app library.

This is how I configure my requireJS:

```js
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/assets/angular',
    paths: {
        pnotify: 'libs/pnotify/pnotify.core',
        // pnotifyButtons: 'libs/pnotify/pnotify.buttons', --> I tried to include the modules but it had no effect
        // pnotifyConfirm: 'libs/pnotify/pnotify.confirm',  --> I tried to include the modules but it had no effect
    }
});
```

This is how I call Pnotify

```js
$scope.deleteData = function() {
  var confirmNotice = new Pnotify({
        text: 'Are you sure to delete this data?',
        type: 'notice',
        icon: false,
        buttons: {
            closer: false,
            sticker: false
          },
        confirm: {confirm:true}
      });
      confirmNotice.get().on('pnotify.confirm', function() {
          alert('Ok, cool.');
      });
      confirmNotice.get().on('pnotify.cancel', function() {
          alert('Oh ok. Chicken, I see.');
      });
};
```

It just returned a 'plain' notification without any buttons on it

PS:

I have included this code on my app init section: PNotify.prototype.options.styling = "fontawesome";
I tried to download PNotify from its site (pnotify.custom.min.js) and it returned the same result (buttons not showing)